# can't put breakpoins on javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webpack, breakpoints

I'm debugging a javascrip code in chrome, but the chrome doesn't let me put breakpoints where I want. I click to put the breakpoint and he puts it some lines before or after the line that a clicked.

I click the line 94, and he puts a break in line 96.

[the code in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCmOa.jpg)

what do I do to debug it?
some help please.

Down here is the webpack.config.development.js

```
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import validate from 'webpack-validator';
import merge from 'webpack-merge';
import formatter from 'eslint-formatter-pretty';
import baseConfig from './webpack.config.base';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

export default validate(merge(baseConfig, {
  debug: true,

  devtool: 'eval-source-map',

  entry: [
    `webpack-hot-middleware/client?
path=http://localhost:${port}/__webpack_hmr`,
    'babel-polyfill',
    './app/styles/main.less',
    './app/index'
  ],

  output: {
    publicPath: `http://localhost:${port}/dist/`
  },

  resolve: {
    fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules')
  },

  resolveLoader: { fallback: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules') },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(less|scss)$/,
        loader: 'style!css!autoprefixer!less'
      },

      // Load images
      { test: /\.jpg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/jpg' },
      { test: /\.gif/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/gif' },
      { test: /\.png/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/png' },
      { test: /\.svg/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg' },

      // Load fonts
      { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'url-loader?
limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff' },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: 'file-
loader' },
    ]
  },

  eslint: {
    formatter
  },

  plugins: [
    // https://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement-with-webpack.html
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),

    // “If you are using the CLI, the webpack process will not exit with an error code by enabling this plugin.”
    // https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#noerrorsplugin
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

    // NODE_ENV should be production so that modules do not perform certain development checks
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })

  ],

  // https://github.com/chentsulin/webpack-target-electron-renderer#how-
this-module-works
  target: 'electron-renderer'
}));
```

Comment: If your source maps are OK, it is most likely an issue with Chrome DevTools...

Answer (score 0):

Use the `debugger;` statement in your code where you want it to pause, if you know where you want to put the breakpoints before running the code.

Make sure the console is open before debugging, because otherwise the breakpoints will be disabled.

Comment: I have put the debugger; statment on the start of the function, but the behavior still the same, doesn't let me put the breaks where I want.

Comment: I've got the idea of the debugger; statement now.better then nothing.